# How to concat macros in C

Tags: c, string, macros, c-preprocessor, string-concatenation

I have a macro that displays the month from `__DATE__` as a numeric value string literal:

```
#define MONTH (\
  __DATE__[2] == 'n' ? (__DATE__[1] == 'a' ? "01" : "06") \
: __DATE__[2] == 'b' ? "02" \
: __DATE__[2] == 'r' ? (__DATE__[0] == 'M' ? "03" : "04") \
: __DATE__[2] == 'y' ? "05" \
: __DATE__[2] == 'l' ? "07" \
: __DATE__[2] == 'g' ? "08" \
: __DATE__[2] == 'p' ? "09" \
: __DATE__[2] == 't' ? "10" \
: __DATE__[2] == 'v' ? "11" \
: "12")
```

This works fine and produces the month I'm looking for. `printf("%s", MONTH);`. However, I'm trying to add this to a larger group of macros and am having trouble:

```
#define MYMONTH "M" MONTH
```

should produce the string: `M11` right now. But instead, it produces the following compiler error:

```
error: called object is not a function or function pointer
#define MYMONTH   "M" MONTH
```

I know you can combine string literals with a macro by appending them:

```
#define COMMA ","
#define EXCLA "!"
#define MYSTR "Hello" COMMA " world" EXCLA
```

But why won't it work when there is logic involved?

Comment: The preprocessor can concatenate string *literals* only. The evaluation of that logic is not done at preprocessing time, but later on—probably at compile time, because it’s a constant expression. E.g., if `__DATE__` expands to `"Oct 31 2016"` then `MONTH` expands to the expression `("Oct 31 2016"[2] == 'n' ? …)`, not a literal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Macros are just a string copy done in preprocessing.

If we copy your `MONTH` macro into `MYMONTH` we get:

```
#define MYMONTH "M" (\
  __DATE__[2] == 'n' ? (__DATE__[1] == 'a' ? "01" : "06") \
: __DATE__[2] == 'b' ? "02" \
: __DATE__[2] == 'r' ? (__DATE__[0] == 'M' ? "03" : "04") \
: __DATE__[2] == 'y' ? "05" \
: __DATE__[2] == 'l' ? "07" \
: __DATE__[2] == 'g' ? "08" \
: __DATE__[2] == 'p' ? "09" \
: __DATE__[2] == 't' ? "10" \
: __DATE__[2] == 'v' ? "11" \
: "12")
```

Which to the compiler looks like you are trying `"M"(<some string here>)`

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. What is the problem with that? You can concat string literals together with macros as I illustrated in the question. `MONTH` will evaluate to be a string literal ("11" right now). So what is wrong with `#define MYMONTH "M" MONTH`?

Comment: ```MONTH``` is evaluated to ```("11")``` so your ```MYMONTH``` evaluates to ```"M"("11")```

Comment: @linsek: you can concatenate string *literals*. You cannot concatenate *expressions*.